# Cannot compare two value of datagridview cell

Tags: vb.net, datagridview, compare

I have parse an data into an datagridview cell like this,

```
Me.DGV.Item(8, Me.DGV.RowCount - 2).Value = Decimal.Parse(datatab.Item(5, i).Value)
Me.DGV.Item(9, Me.DGV.RowCount - 2).Value = Decimal.Parse(datatab.Item(5, i).Value)
```

Then, in the end of process, I compare it for validation reason (Because item at cell [9,row] may edited. The comparison is just like this,

```
If Decimal.Parse(Me.DGV.Item(9, i).Value) = Decimal.Parse(Me.DGV.Item(8, i).Value + "000") Then
    MessageBox.Show("Jumlah tidak sesuai dengan Nominal", "Warning", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Warning)
    Exit Function
End If
```

So, result is may true while it have same value or no in opposite condition. But in my case, it will return false value while values are equal and true value while values are not equal.
Anyone figured it out?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put a breakpoint at the If line and check both sides of the equality comparison.
Generally, if you want to add three zeroes at the end of a decimal number that you treat functionally, it is more convenient to manipulate the number itself once it's already parsed.
So i would do something like

```
If Decimal.Parse(Me.DGV.Item(9, i).Value) = Decimal.Parse(Me.DGV.Item(8, i).Value) * 1000 Then
```

Also, check that the values from the grid have the correct format for input that decimal.Parse needs.